# Cannot figure out why epel is not showing up on yum repolist

Tags: centos

I'm trying to add epel.repo on Centos 7. It seems like it is getting installed fine but it doesn't show up in the list and cannot use it. Here are the commands I run and their output. Am I missing something else?

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================
 Package                             Arch                          Version                      Repository                     Size
====================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 epel-release                        noarch                        7-5                          extras                         14 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 14 k
Installed size: 24 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : epel-release-7-5.noarch                                                                                          1/1
  Verifying  : epel-release-7-5.noarch                                                                                          1/1

Installed:
  epel-release.noarch 0:7-5

Complete!

$ yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
ypc-released                                                                                                                113/113
repo id                                                      repo name                                                        status
base/x86_64                                                  RHEL-7.2 - Base                                                  9,007
extras/x86_64                                                RHEL-7.2 - Updates Released                                        191
updates-released/x86_64                                      RHEL-7.2 - Updates Released                                        369
ypc-released/x86_64                                          RHEL-7.2 - Ypc Released                                            113
repolist: 9,680

$ cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
$ ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr  7 18:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 104 root root 12288 Apr  7 02:01 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1664 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1309 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-CR.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   649 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   290 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   630 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1331 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-Sources.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1952 Dec  9 09:59 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   957 Nov 25  2014 epel.repo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1056 Nov 25  2014 epel-testing.repo

$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No packages marked for update

$ sudo yum list --enablerepo=epel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks


Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found
```

Here is the epel.repo

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: try `yum repolist enabled` and  `yum repolist all` to see if maybe you just don't have epel enabled

Comment: @Liam both results are the same. yum repolist all shows all of them as enabled but epel is not in that list.

Comment: if it doesn't show up on `yum repolist all` then it isn't properly installed.  Go [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and download the .rpm you want (alternately `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm`). Then run `rpm -ivh <your rpm>`. This should be all you need to do. You might want to `sudo yum remove epel-release` first just to get rid of what you have and start fresh

Comment: @Liam thanks for the answer but I have done that several times. As you can see in my question, it shows that epel is "successfully" installed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the output of `yum repolist`, I see the repo names are "RHEL-7.2 - Base", but on a CentOS7 system, it would just be BaseOS.  None of the repositories named in `yum repolist` correspond to the files you showed in `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

So, either you ran `yum repolist` on a different host than the one that produced the output of the yum.repos.d listing, or the `yum` on your computer looks for repos in a different directory.  It certainly shouldn't be claiming to have RHEL-7.2 repositories.  I've never heard of someone writing a RHEL clone that used repos other than /etc/yum.repos.d/, except RHEL's old rhn yum plugin, but that would show up in the output of yum.

Comment: Thank you. You're absolutely right. in /etc/yum.conf there was this line reposdir=/etc/false. Changing this solved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

Open `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` in an editor and look for a line that starts with `enabled=`.  If it's set to zero, you won't get any packages from that repo in `yum search` or `yum install`.  To correct this, change the `0` to a `1` on that line.

Many repos are set to not be enabled by default to keep you from accidentally blowing out packages you're relying upon.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just added the epel.repo into my question. The first [epel] repo is already enabled.

Comment: Do you have `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7` on your system?  Also, you may need to run `yum makecache`.  Can you also add the output of `yum repolist`?

Comment: I don't see /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7 under that folder however the epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm is there. `yum repolist output is actually in the question.

Comment: It's so poorly set up (=>centos). I mean you *install* a repo, you try to *use* a repo and it remains enabled=0 just like that. How clumsy is it to have to nano into the obscure repo file and change an obscure setting for it work.  I don't get Centos complications.

Comment: It's somewhat cumbersome, but it makes sense when you realize that "installing" a repository and "making a repository's packages available" are two separate steps which _by design_ are separate because a new repository might have (for example) a newer major release of a software package you have installed that you're not expecting or other potentially breaking change lurking for an unmonitored `yum update`.